# Push to a new window using navigation controller using rubymotion

Tags: ruby, controller, navigation, window, rubymotion

I'm kind of new to object oriented programming, but I have experience with scripting and **ruby(motion)s syntax**. I can't figure out how to simply push to a new window using a navigationcontroller.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might want to try ProMotion. It's made to handle these things seamlessly. (/shameless plug) https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion

Answer (score 0):

It's real simple!   Your current controller has a `navigationController` attached to it.   You can access that with `self.navigationController`.  Now just create an instance of the second controller (or Window as you call it) and use `pushViewController` to push it!

```
@second_view_controller = MyOtherViewController.alloc.init # or .new
self.navigationController.pushViewController(@second_view_controller, animated:true)
```

That should work great!  If you want to simplify this in the future, I suggest you check out the [ProMotion](https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion) gem, where you could replace the above code with something simple like:

```
open MyOtherViewController
```

wouldn't that be much better!?

If you'd like more examples of the traditional (non-gem) methodology, try looking at this example code:  https://github.com/IconoclastLabs/rubymotion_cookbook/tree/master/ch_2/09_arrayofviewcontrollers